# Python program that runs a game of pig with a human player and the computer

Tags: python, python-3.x, probability, dice

So in a nutshell, who goes first is decided randomly. When the human players turn does come up, he/she has the option to either hold or roll. If he chooses to roll, a dice is rolled and the values are added(to turn_score) till it is >20 after which it is the computers turn.

The turn score is added to the final score after every turn. If a 1 rolls up, the turn score becomes 0(the final does NOT change).

Any advice on  where I am going wrong with this one?

```
import random
def roll_dice():
    return random.randint(1,6)

players = ['Player One', 'Player Two']
scores = {'Player One': 0, 'Player Two': 0}
random.shuffle(players)

while True:
    for i in players:
        if i == 'Player One':
            choice = input("Roll(r) or Hold(h)?: ")
            turn_score = 0
            final_score = 0
            if (choice=='r'):
                while(turn_score<=20):
                    dice_value = roll_dice()
                    turn_score += dice_value
                    if (dice_value==1):
                        turn_score = 0
                        print("-rolled a ",dice_value)
                        print("Pigged out!")
                        break
                    print("Turn score is: ",turn_score)
                    final_score += turn_score
                    print("Your final score is: ",final_score)
                    if (final_score>100):
                        break
        else:
            turn_score=0
            print("It is " +  str(i) + "'s turn.")
            while(turn_score<20):
                dice_value = roll_dice()
                if (dice_value==1):
                    turn_score = 0
                    scores[i] +=0
                    print("- rolled a ",dice_value)
                    print("Pigged out!")
                    break
                else:
                    turn_score+=dice_value
                    print("-rolled a ",dice_value)
        scores[i] += turn_score
        print("Turn score is: ",turn_score)
        print('{} score: {} {} score: {}'.format(players[0], scores[players[0]], players[1], scores[players[1]]))
        if scores[i]>100:
            break
    if scores[i]>100:
        break

winner = [winner for winner in scores if scores[winner] == max(scores.values())]
print(str(winner) + " is the winner!")`
```

Here is what I am getting as an output:

```
It is Player Twos turn.
-rolled a  3
-rolled a  5
-rolled a  5
-rolled a  5
-rolled a  4
Turn score is:  22
Player Two score: 22 Player One score: 0
Roll(r) or Hold(h)?: h
It is Player Twos turn.
- rolled a  1
Pigged out!
Turn score is:  0
Player Two score: 22 Player One score: 0
Roll(r) or Hold(h)?: r
Turn score is:  3
Your final score is:  3
Turn score is:  5
Your final score is:  8
Turn score is:  9
Your final score is:  17
Turn score is:  13
Your final score is:  30
Turn score is:  16
Your final score is:  46
Turn score is:  19
Your final score is:  65
-rolled a  1
Pigged out!
It is Player Twos turn.
- rolled a  1
Pigged out!
Turn score is:  0
Player Two score: 22 Player One score: 0
Roll(r) or Hold(h)?:
```

Comment: Could you expand a bit on what is wrong with the current output? I don't know the general rules of pig and it's not entirely clear from your question what the expected output should be.

Comment: @JennerFelton Apologies. The problem lies with the adding part of turn score and final score. Say its my turn and I decide to roll i.e. press r. It should show exactly how it shows the computers turn. It is weird( 5+3=8 but shows as 9) whenever the player rolls.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, unless I'm missunderstanding the game, I think your issue is that you are adding the turn score to the final score *on each round*, instead of adding the difference between the turn score and the original final score on each round (i.e. you are giving the player  points for previous rolls on that turn even if they roll a 1 on a subsequent roll).

Instead of:

```
        turn_score = 0
        final_score = 0
        if (choice=='r'):
            while(turn_score<=20):
                dice_value = roll_dice()
                turn_score += dice_value
                if (dice_value==1):
                    turn_score = 0
                    print("-rolled a ",dice_value)
                    print("Pigged out!")
                    break
                print("Turn score is: ",turn_score)
                final_score += turn_score
                print("Your final score is: ",final_score)
                if (final_score>100):
                    break
```

I think you want:

```
        turn_score = 0
        final_score = 0
        if (choice=='r'):
            while(turn_score<=20):
                dice_value = roll_dice()
                turn_score += dice_value
                if dice_value == 1:
                    turn_score = 0
                    print("-rolled a ",dice_value)
                    print("Pigged out!")
                    break
                print("Turn score is: ", turn_score)
                print("Your final score is: ", final_score + turn_score)
                if final_score + turn_score > 100:
                    final_score += turn_score
                    break
```

Comment: Thanks! I will try to understand your code! It works so far! But the final score sometimes crosses 110...

Comment: @ggezpython3 Sorry if I didn't include enough explanation with my code. The only real difference between what I did and what you did is that I didn't add `turn_score` to `final_score` until `final_score` is over `100`. Looking at it again, I think my code actually doesn't work correctly (as the while loop could end without incrementing the final score).